# Load hiera file from specific variable/fact/hiera-value

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying to load a hiera file according to a specific flag.

Hiera hierarachy configuration is

```
:hierarchy:
  - "%{environment}/%{::fqdn}"
  - "%{environment}/%{nodetype}"
  - "%{environment}/%{calling_module}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - "common/%{calling_module}"
  - "common"
```

In fact in want to factorize some configuration at the "nodetype" level. Goal is to avoid putting the same hiera "block" inside files:

- environment/test/myhost1.example.com.yaml
- environment/test/myhost2.example.com.yaml
- environment/test/myhost3.example.com.yaml

but instead but common part in :

- environment/test/nfs-server.yaml for all nfs servers related common configuration
- environment/test/backend-server.yaml for all backend servers related common

After that all servers would get their own specific values with the fqdn yaml file. (this part is ok)

Currently, i don't know how to provide the "nodetype" data to hiera context.

I tried to put it into the main manifest file like (yeah I read the doc and I know it a bad idea but even with despair attempt, it don't work anyway)

```
node 'nfs1.example.com', 'nfs2.example.com' {
  $nodetype= 'nfs-server'
```

but the file *environment/test/nfs-server.yaml* is not loaded by hiera.

I also tried to use custom fact but using a custom fact with

```
modules/hosts/facts.d/host-fact-test.txt
```

File is send to the host of the agent but again here, hiera don't use the dedicated file.

```
Notice: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d/host-fact-test.txt]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}d7492faae1bfe55f65f9958a7a5f6df9'
```

If I use a **notify** puppet command, the value is ok

```
if $nodetype== 'nfs-server' {
  notify {"Running with \$nodetype ${nodetype} ID defined":
    withpath => true,
  }
}
```

result:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/attemps/Notify[Running with $nodetype nfs-server ID defined]/message: Running with $nodetype nfs-server ID defined
```

Stack is Puppet opensource on Ubuntu 14 so versions are:

- puppet 3.8.4
- hiera  1.3.4
- facter 2.4.4

Any idea or suggestion to make it work (or achieve a similar behavior) ?

Comment: have tried using %{::nodetype} ?

Comment: Yes putting `%{::nodetype}` or `%{nodetype}` don't change a thing in /etc/hiera.yaml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Puppet master process usually does not use the configuration in `/etc/hiera.yaml`, which can be confusing. With Puppet `3.x`, it's usually `/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml`.

You can make sure using (as root)

```
puppet master --configprint hiera_config
```

on the master machine.

Comment: **puppet master --configprint hiera_config** is  **/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml** so the right hiera file is used.

Comment: @TheCodeKiller OK, I was mislead by your earlier comment alluding to `/etc/hiera.yaml` then. To debug this, you will want to run `hiera -d -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml <key> ::fqdn=nfs1.example.com nodetype=nfs-server`. It shows you information about the data source lookups.

Comment: It shows the attended value as it use the right value from the **nfs-server.yaml** file as attended using _nearly_ (just add the environment) the provided command line. We retest it with a *notify*, and it seems to work now ! We will perform additional tests to ensure all is fine now.